# Validate user id with Ocelot API gateway

Tags: .net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

i am implementing some microservices that communicate with a monolith, all done with .net core.
Currently my gateway validates that the user jwt token is valid, based on it´s structure, but the thing is, i need to pass a user id(from the monolith) to the microservice, and i was told that it needed to be validated.
So with that in mind, what approach should i follow to validate that the user id that is being passed to the microservice exists?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all IMO jwt tokens should be created by a trusted party, and whatever it contains should be already valid, so no jwt token should be provided by the IdentityProvider if the user doesn't exist in the first place.

But if you must do it this way, you could create a custom middleware for that scenario, that reads the token from the requests and validates that the userid exists.

You can read more about custom middlewares [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Your middleware could look something like this:

```
public class UserIdValidatprMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestCultureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IIdentityService identityService, IUserStore userStore)
    {
        var userId = identityService.GetUserIdFromToken();
        var userExists = await userStore.CheckIfUserExists(userId);
        if (!userExists) throw SomeException();
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: then you advise my gateway has a middleware that requests the DB where the user is, to check if that id exists?

Comment: If the gateway is a separate microservice, than the database call should be implemented in the service responsible for user handling and it should be published e.g. as an endpoint. Then, instead of a database call, you should create an http request to that endpoint in the middleware.

Comment: I renamed the IDatabase service to IUserStore in my answer, so that it doesn't imply a database call

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was really clarifying and i will mark it as the right one, because it makes sense